# Django Model Formset With ManyToMany Inline

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to store groups of pages under different tags. So I create these models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pages = models.ManyToManyField(Page)
```

I would then like to create a model form(set?) that will allow me to edit the tag, and every page attached to that tag, as one big form. I believe this is what happens when you use Model Inline Formset, but that uses foreign keys. This is a reusable app, right now I'm just rendering the form in a template, but I would prefer to use django forms so it's easier to reuse.

I can't seem to figure out how this is done, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem, but I was using a generic relation please study my post link is given below. U can use inline formset in the same way. If you have any more problem u can get back to me.

< [Creating form using Generic_inlineformset_factory from the Model Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304148/creating-form-using-generic-inlineformset-factory-from-the-model-form) >

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the project has been shelved for the time being, however I was able to get some useful information from your answer so I'll mark it as accepted. I wish I had more time to post a better update than that.